# What is a servicing stack? Windows 10 system was updated a few days ago. Can I uninstall it?

Tags: windows-10, windows-update

What is a servicing stack? Windows 10 system was updated a few days ago. Can I uninstall it?

Comment: Why do you want to uninstall something that is a part of Windows? What is the problem?

Comment: [From Microsoft documentation.](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/deployment/update/servicing-stack-updates)

Comment: “Can I uninstall it?” - No; It’s also required to receive future Windows Updates

Comment: _Can I uninstall it?_ – **YES** you can! I did it on my laptop, and I intend to explain _how_ I did it. Until then, bear with me.

Answer (score -1):

Servicing Stack is the Windows Modules Installer that handles Installation of Windows updates, it is necessary to continue successful updates to Windows, so NO, do not uninstall it.

[More info here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/error-message-when-you-install-a-msu-update-package-on-a-computer-that-is-running-windows-the-windows-modules-installer-must-be-updated-before-you-can-install-this-package-fe8d5770-df2e-f020-b47c-6605b0de15ba)

Comment: This is a comment. Not an answer.

Comment: It sure does..."What is a servicing stack?" I explained that and the second question. See if you can do better with your own answer.

Comment: Again, this is a comment. Not an answer as defined by this site. You have 56.3k right now. It is inconceivable to me you would not know what a comment versus an answer is.

Comment: You are wrong!!

Comment: _NO, do not uninstall it._
I respectfully disagree.
There may be a lot of good reasons why you may want to uninstall it.

Comment: @Henke , so give some good reasons.

Comment: I might be wrong on this one. I'm still learning about these things. For example, I only recently realized that each Servicing Stack corresponds to a build version. Removing a Servicing Stack means uninstalling a build version. I can see why this might be undesirable. Anyway, what I had in mind was _troubleshooting_. If you want to rule out that some problem depends on a specific Servicing Stack, one way to do it is to uninstall that Servicing Stack and see what happens.